# Sampling data uniformly across labels

Tags: python

I have a dataframe with N rows and 4 columns : id, label1, label2, label3.
Each label has k(i) classes. For example, label1 has k(1)=5 classes.

I want to sample n example the more uniformly across labels :
the result of the sampling should have 100/k(1)% of n elements (if k(1)=5 and n=100 then 20 elements) in each class of label1 while also having 100/k(2)% of n elements in each class of label2 and having 100/k(3)% of n elements in each class of label3.

I know that there is not always a mathematical solution to this problem, but I want to optimize the sampling under those constraints.
Ideas ? :)

Comment: Use scikit-learn 'train_test_split' with the 'stratify' flag.

Comment: Doesn't work. Read my problem again thx.

Comment: Of course it does not, you have to do some work on your dataframe first, for example using groupby, to make a 'class' column out of your 'label's columns. Post the code you have written up to now so that one can understand your problem.